# Get items values of ListBox with SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, listboxitem

I've got for example `ListBox` with two `TextBlock`s like this:

```
<ListBox Name="listboxNews"
         SelectionChanged="listboxNews_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="400"
                        Height="70">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" name="title" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" name="desc" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And as you can see, I've got `listboxNews_SelectionChanged` method, in which i need to select Text of first TextBlock (if posibble by name so it will be independent on order of textblocks), but this one, which I select. For example if first item has title "Item 1" and second "Item 2" and I click on second one, i need to get "Item 2". I was trying something with listboxNews.Items, but i guess this is not correct. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelectedItem property will hold the currently selected object. You can just cast that and take the Title property.

Try this code:

```cs
private void listboxNews_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  var current = listboxNews.SelectedItem as MyObjectType;
  MessageBox.Show(current.Title);
}
```

Change `MyObjectType` with the type of your object.

Comment: I do it, but I still get **NullReferenceException**. My class `News` has variable `public string Title { get; set; }` but when I do `var current = listboxNews.SelectedItem as News;`, `current.Title` still seems to be null...

Comment: In my `connectNews_DownloadStringCompleted()` is:

`News = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            listboxNews.ItemsSource = from news in News.Descendants("newsItem")
                                      select new News
                                      {
                                          Title = news.Element("title").Value,
                                          Description = news.Element("description").Value,
                                      };`

Comment: Which one is null? listboxNews.SelectedItem or only when you cast it to news? Put a break point in the SelectionChanged event and check the value type of listBoxNew.SelectedItem in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy and paste out of a working Windows Phone 8 solution.

This was also tested successfully in WPF.

```
    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (UIElement item in (sender as ListBox).Items)
                {
                    if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem == item)
                    {
                        foreach (UIElement InnerItem in (item as StackPanel).Children)
                        {
                            if ((InnerItem is TextBlock) && (InnerItem as TextBlock).Name.Equals("title"))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show((InnerItem as TextBlock).Text);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: No... What i need to do is this - I've got ListBox filled with news (each news per one ListBox line/item) and after click on some item, I want to open detail page for this news... To do this, I need to pass title as parameter to detail page so I need title value for selected item.

Comment: Then you can use the name for what ever you want.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" name="title" />` I need `Text` value for currently selected ListBox item.

Comment: @PavelŠtěrba dont forget to add the if clause inside the first foreach otherwise it will print all titles and not just the selected one

Comment: Now it throws InvalidCastException in __foreach (UIElement item in (sender as ListBox).Items)__

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29760/discussion-between-pavel-strba-and-amr)

Comment: @PavelŠtěrba no need. The code I posted I tested in both WPF and in Windows Phone 8. The code I posted works for the code given. You need to post a new question if you are having other underlying issues.

Comment: Why you do not use the MVVM with its Databinding?