# Get data from clicked item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am new to Windows Phone,

I have one listbox with textblocks in it, I want to fetch all data from selected item in listbox.

Here is my code snippet:

**.xaml  file**

```
 <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="9,10,0,0" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="0,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top""/>
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttractionName}" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="120,-110,0,0""/>
                                 <TextBlock Text="Price:" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30""/>
                                 <TextBlock Text="£" Foreground="Green" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="40" Margin="200,-50,12,0""/>
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding price}" Foreground="Green" FontSize="40""/>
                                 <Line X1="0" X2="420" Y1="10" Y2="10" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**.cs file**

```
    void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(" You selected " +listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

My console shows output this way:  `You selected Appname.Pagename.methodname`

Class which is bound to ListBox

```
    public class Attractions { 
[JsonProperty("AttractionName")]
 public string AttractionName { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("IphoneImage")] 
public string IphoneImage { get; set; } 
[JsonProperty("price")] public string price { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways to do it:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    Attractions first = listbox1.SelectedItem as Attractions ;
    Attractions second = (Attractions)listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
    Attractions third = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Attractions;
    Attractions fourth = args.AddedItems[0] as Attractions;

    Debug.WriteLine(" You selected " + first.AttractionName);
}
```

With SelectedItem (Index) you get an item that is Type of your ItemsSource Collection. Once you get the item you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `SelectionChange Event` put the following code

```
Attractions  lbi = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Attractions;
```

you can access the properties of the class using

```
lbi.price
```

Comment: unable to access `Price` in `SelectionChange Event`

Comment: Share your class you have use to bind the listbox

Comment: i have added your class code to your question, delete it from comments

Comment: what are you getting when writing lbi. ?

Comment: shows: `You selected Appname.AttractionPage.Attraction+Attractions`

Answer (score 0):

write this code

This Can Help You

```
void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(" You selected " +listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString ());
    }
```

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491236/get-items-values-of-listbox-with-selectedindex