# How to get Item Click Event(which Item is selected) in windows Phone ListBox.ItemTemplate Panorama application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can I get Selected/touch Item Detail in windows Phone ListBox.ItemTemplate
As following is the code for Build in template

```
<!--Panorama item one-->
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="second item" Name="ptHeader1" >
            <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
            <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFE5001b" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

And I have try following Code in .cs file code.

```
    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        ptHeader1.Header = String.Format("   You selected {0}.", lbi.Content);
    }
```

But I was not able to get selected Item Information.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480453/get-data-from-clicked-item-in-listbox/21480728#21480728 was almost the same problem

Comment: Please update your question adding the Class for the object you are Binding on the Listbox

Answer (score 0):

When you databind a ListBox like you did with `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` the `SelectedItem` property in your SelectionChanged handler contains one of those items, not a `ListBoxItem`.

Try something like this:

```
YourClass selectedItem = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as YourClass;
if(selectedItem != null)
{
    var lineOne = selectedItem.LineOne;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to select `ListBox` item:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItemType lbi = ListBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItemType;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ptHeader1.Header = String.Format("   You selected {0}.", (sender as ListBox).SelectedText);
}
```